# C++: Create a template function that only allows classes which have inherited a particular interface?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I would like to write:

```
class JsonSerializable {
public:
  virtual JsonDocument toJsonDocument();
  virtual void fromJsonDocument();
}
```

And a function:

```
void readJson(foo &foo, string path){
  // file open and close machinery
  JsonDocument = get_json_doc(file);
  foo.fromJsonDocument(JsonDocument);
}
```

Now, I want to immediately write:

```
template <class T>
void readJson(T &t,...){
   ...
};
```

And it is now generic, with the problem being: I can't restrict the use of the template function to only classes which are `JsonSerializable`.

How does one accomplish this task by modifying the following line:

```
template<class T> // somehow restrict T to "T such that T is also JsonSerializable"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is also JsonSerializable"? Should it have the same interface? Or any type that inherits from `JsonSerializable`?

Comment: if the template uses the interface then practically `T` is restricted, because if it does not provide the interface there will be compiler errors. Restricting to subclasses is a bit uncommon, if anyhow you are using runtime polymorphism you do not really need the template and the method could simple take a parameter of type `JsonSerializable&`

Comment: Since you have an interface, and you want to take only objects that implement that interface... then why not simply `readJson(JsonSerializable &foo, string path)`?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica lol I am trying to come up with an example that motivates the answer...

Comment: If you are using templates, why not `template<typename T> concept JsonSerializable = requires(T t) { { t.toJsonDocument() } -> std::convertible_to<JsonDocument>; { t.fromJsonDocument() }; }`

Comment: @Caleth this looks like the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `std::is_base_of` with a `static_assert`-

`std::is_base_of<B, D>` check at compile time if D is derived from B.

`static_assert` perform a compile time check which cause a compiler error if tested for `false`.

With these you can check if `T`  is a `Serializable` object:

```
template <class T>
void read(const T& t){
   static_assert(std::is_base_of<Serializable, T>::value, "class need to be Serializable");
};
```

Here is a **[Live Sample](http://cpp.sh/5m5ag)**

Comment: this is sort of a work around, though, isn't it? Because, ideally, the IDE can discover what can go into the function by examining the grammar, rather than fail at runtime with an informative message.

Comment: This is not a workaround at all. This is a language lawyer. You are stating this method is acceptable with these rules, giving you an error saying "me, the programmer, has given a rule to this method and you are not following it". Without it T is fine everything use methods used inside. Any class with a `toJsonDocument()` method can be used inside it, which is contrary to the statement of your question "only allows classes which have inherited a particular interface"

Comment: @donlan that is not a runtime informative message. That is a **compile time** check. It will not compile if the rule is broken. Have you checked the live sample?